# Shared calendar is not updated automaticly anymore.

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

A shared calendar is not automaticly updated anymore. When the user creates an element in this shared calendar it does not get sync. with the calnedar, so others don't see it.

But when he presses update folder (in the menu - send/recive) then the calendar gets updated/synced too.

What could cause the problem that it does not get updated automaticly anymore?